# How to set table column width for dynamic drop down list?

Tags: css, width, html-table

I have a table with a dynamic drop down list.

The width of the drop down will change depending on its content.

I would like the table column to be the same as the width of the drop down.

If I set a width less than the size of the dropdown IE seems make the column bigger than the drop down whilst wrapping the column title it inserts whitespace on either side of the dropdown.

Is there a way in CSS to say just make the column the same size as its content?

Here is a sample html table that includes my current fix (kludge)

```
<table id="mappingtable" width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="80px">FixedWidthColumn</th>
    <th width="80%">ExpandingColumn</th>
    <th width="122px">&nbsp;</th>
    <th>DynamicColumn</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td align="center">Button</td>
    <td align="center">DropDownList</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem exists without any css

If I remove the width="80%" from the expanding column the dynamic column will have whitespace

I have tried width: auto on the dynamic column and setting it to a fixed width but none of these work for me

Comment: Yes. Probably. If you could show us your html and current css we'd probably be specific and -hopefully- more useful to you.

Comment: Is the column title wider than the drop-down?

Comment: No the column title only wraps if i set the width to a small value

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a table with a width 100% and 1 column without a width defined. The column with the dropdown can have a realy small width and the browser will automatically make the whole column match the width of the dropdown.

The HTML would look like this:

```
<table width="100%" >
  <tr>
    <th width="80">FixedWidthColumn</th>
    <th>ExpandingColumn</th>
    <th width="122"> </th>
    <th width="10">DynamicColumn</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td align="center">Button</td>
    <td align="center">DropDownList</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As an answer to the remarks below, there are some solutions you can explore:

You could possibly add a an option tag to your dropdown list that is at least a certain width and some no-breaking spaces like so:

```
<option>Please select...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
```

You could give the select tag a minimum width like so:

```
<select style="min-width: 200px;" >
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion beforehand, if i use a small width for the column the heading gets wrapped and the dropdown has a large block of whitespace on either side of it if it is larger than the column

Comment: Try putting the heading in a <nobr> tag. That should keep it from wrapping.

Comment: Setting **width="10"** on the dynamic column worked when I tried this example. I tested with **Internet Explorer 7**, **Firefox 3.5.1** and **Opera 9.64**.  What browser and version are you testing with? Also, what DOCTYPE is specified on top in the HTML (if any) ?

Comment: The DOCTYPE is as follows

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you, for this specific table, override the css data inside of the table parameters?

Where that parameter is passed in (or parsed somewhere else).

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you mean?

What I have been able to do is set the width of a different column to be like 60% and left this drop down column with no widht setting.  This achieves my goal but seems ugly, as this approach also squishes my fixed width columns

Comment: Yes, you can set the width parameter in your table as such: width="${myTable.width}" where the myTable.width is a parameter that is set somewhere else (calculated)

Answer (score 0):

That's how tables work, if there are 2 columns without a width set and the table width is set, the remaining available space will be distributed between the 2 columns.

Removing the 100% width from the table would solve your problem if the content in ExpandingColumn is big enough to fill the remaining width.